# Can you see who all favorited your question?

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks

When someone marks your question on SO as a favorite, you get to see a star and the number of users that marked the question as their favorite. Is there a way to see who all marked it as a favorite?

If not, it would be a nice feature for SO to have.

Comment: I have to ask, why would this be a nice feature to have?

Comment: I would agree, I wish we  had this feature as well.